# Mac brew doctor show Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin

Tags: macos, homebrew

I try to upgrade python2.7 to python3 on macOS Catalina, when I run `brew doctor`, it shows:

```
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

So I try the command `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` which did not works.

Answer (score 32):

Apple macOS has moved from Bash shell to Zsh (Z Shell).

*Solution:*

Run the command below in your terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Now quit the terminal by pressing `command+q`, re-open the terminal and run `brew doctor`

Answer (score 11):

You need to close and re-open your terminar after applying:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 7):

After some search I found the commands that works for me:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: `source` operations would be applied after you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `brew doctor` in the IDE terminal, then do it in the system terminal, it should work